# asp.net opc web trend controls are not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, trend

opc web trend (asp.net) controls are not displayed and showing Cross marks when configured with IIS7. Working fine in visual studio but when i publish this with IIS, it just shows cross marks. Below is the code.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication7._Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="OPCWebTrends" namespace="OPCWebTrends" tagprefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register assembly="OPCWebControls" namespace="OPCWebControls" tagprefix="cc2" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Dart.PowerWEB.LiveControls" namespace="Dart.PowerWEB.LiveControls" tagprefix="cc3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 15px; position: relative; height: 616px; width: 1298px; background-color: #FFCC99">

        <br />
        <br />
        <div style="border-style: outset; border-width: inherit; border-color: #0000FF; height: 435px">

             <cc1:OPCWebTrend ID="OPCWebTrend2" runat="server" Height="379px" Width="490px" />
        <cc2:OPCWebRefresh ID="OPCWebRefresh1" runat="server">
        </cc2:OPCWebRefresh>

        </div>
        <br />
        <br />

        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a bad first post @Umar Abbasi. It explains the problem you are having, but ending your description of the problem with a question will help you get a more concise answer. Please consider adding something that would help a reviewer get you to your goal.

Comment: @Lawrence Johnson thanks for the response. i want to know what is wrong with control because i can see it inside div but it just shows cross mark like missing image or something... i am also facing issue in css and jquerry in my other web application .. it works fine with visual studio but on server it just dont recognize css and jquerry . kindly guide me what can i do to make this thing work .